# ¿ Como puedo obtener el historial de descarga por meses de una aplicación X (cualquier app) con Python Scrapy?

Tags: python, google-play, scrapy

Tengo una duda acerca de los datos sobre las aplicación de la Play Store. Realice un scraping de los datos de la apps de store, pero solo obtengo datos genéricos. ¿Existe una forma de obtener los datos sobre las descargas segmentado por meses de cualquier app mediante Python?

Comment: Si el html de la pagina no muestra esa información no puedes rasparla porque no existe.

Comment: Como dice RicharlyxD, `scrappy`solo lee y parsea codigo html. Solo te podrá mostrar lo que ya muestre las paginas que uses, nada más.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el data :)